# Multithreaded merge sort programming

Tags: c++, multithreading, sorting

[This is the experiment result - runtime of original verison, multiprocess version, and multithread version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks8nn.png)I am comparing the performance of merge sort programming between using multi-processes and multi threads. The comparison is down in terms of the number of threads/processes, the number of elements in an array. What makes me depressed is the counter-intuitive result: *as increasing the number of threads/processes, the runtime increases;* the multiprocess version is almost 10 times faster than the other one. As I expected, the multi thread version should win. I attach the multi-thread source code. Please help me to see what happened. Thank you all!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

// number of elements in array
// number of threads

int MAX;
int THREAD_MAX;
// array bellow is to store the right edge of a divided array
int index[20] = {0};
int p_i = 0;

using namespace std;

int *a;
int part = 0;
// merge function for merging two parts
void merge(int l1, int h1, int h2) {
    int count = h2 - l1 + 1;
    int sorted[count];
    int i = l1, k = h1 + 1, m = 0;
    while (i <= h1 && k <= h2) {
        if (a[i]<a[k])
            sorted[m++] = a[i++];
        else if (a[k]<a[i])
            sorted[m++] = a[k++];
        else if (a[i] == a[k]) {
            sorted[m++] = a[i++];
            sorted[m++] = a[k++];
        }
    }
    while (i <= h1)
        sorted[m++] = a[i++];

    while (k <= h2)
        sorted[m++] = a[k++];

    int arr_count = l1;
    for (i = 0; i<count; i++, l1++)
        a[l1] = sorted[i];
}

// merge sort function
void merge_sort(int low, int high) {
    // calculating mid point of array
    int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
    if (low < high) {

        // calling first half
        merge_sort(low, mid);

        // calling second half
        merge_sort(mid + 1, high);

        // merging the two halves
        merge(low, mid, high);
    }
}

// thread function for multi-threading
void* merge_sort(void* arg) {
    int thread_part = part++;

    // calculating low and high
    int low = thread_part * (MAX / THREAD_MAX);
    int high = (thread_part + 1) * (MAX / THREAD_MAX) - 1;

    // allocate the rest part of original array to the last thread
    if(thread_part == THREAD_MAX -1){
        high = MAX - 1;
    }
    // store the right edge of each divided array
    index[++p_i] = high;

    // evaluating mid point
    int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;

    merge_sort(low, mid);
    merge_sort(mid + 1, high);
    merge(low, mid, high);

}
void isSorted(int len) {
    if (len == 1) {
        printf("Sorting Done Successfully\n");
        return;
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 1; i<len; i++) {
        if (a[i]<a[i - 1]) {
            printf("Sorting Not Done\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("Sorting Done Successfully\n");
    return;
}
// Driver Code
int main() {


    cout << "Enter No of elements of Array:";
    cin >> MAX;

    cout << "Enter No of Thread:";
    cin >> THREAD_MAX;


    // generating random values in array
    a = new int[MAX];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        a[i] = rand();
    }

    // t1 and t2 for calculating time for merge sort

    clock_t t1 = clock();
    pthread_t threads[THREAD_MAX];

    // creating threads
    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_MAX; i++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, merge_sort, (void*)NULL);
    }


    // joining all threads
    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_MAX; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    // merging the final parts
    int p = 1;
    int mid, high;
    for(int q = 1; q < THREAD_MAX; q++) {   

        mid = index[p];
        p++;
        high = index[p];
        merge(0, mid, high);            
    }

    clock_t t2 = clock();
    cout << "Time taken: " << (double)(t2 - t1)/ CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    isSorted(MAX);

    // displaying sorted array
    /*cout << "Sorted array: ";
      for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
      cout << a[i] << " ";*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: `int sorted[count];` is not valid C++, it uses VLA extension.

Comment: I am trying to figure out what`s the problem with the code.

Comment: Jarod42： Is that what makes my code incorrect?

Comment: You have concurrent accesses without synchronization of some variables (`part`, `p_i`) leading to UB.

Comment: Same with `a` in `merge`

Comment: @MegaMM Undefined behavior is just that - undefined, it doesn't mean that there should, ever, be an error.

Comment: Same with index[]. Overall I suspect that a lot of time is spend on the final merges. More threads mean more loops for the final merges with larger and larger chunks to merge. With 20 threads the final merge is 10 times more work than each thread does.

Comment: Throwing more threads at a problem won't necessarily make it faster. How big is the input you're testing?

Comment: @Kevin i tried 10000, 20000, 2000000.

Comment: I did a similar experiment, but using bottom up merge sort, sorting 16 million pseudo random 32 bit integers on a 4 core processor. The 4 thread version was 3 x faster, the 8 thread version 3.9 x faster, probably memory bandwidth limited at that point. [example code from a code review question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148025/multithreaded-bottom-up-merge-sort) .

Comment: @rcgldr  I have seen your code before, but it`s too complicated to follow. Could you run my code in your PC?

Comment: @MegaMM - the example I wrote is windows specific. The only complicated part is the overhead of creating Windows threads, and the semaphores I use to prevent the threads from running before everything is setup. To avoid the issues with variables shared between threads, I recommend splitting up the array and setting up the associated variables before starting any of the threads. Also `merge()` uses `sorted[]`, which is allocated from the stack, which won't work for larger arrays. Use `new` and `delete` instead.

Comment: @MegaMM - also as pointed out by my example code, having more threads than cores / hyper threads will slow the process down. There was little gain in going from 4 threads to 8 threads on a 4 core processor with hyper threading. You mention multi-processing, but not how the memory was shared. With multi-processing each process has a separate address space, and I'm wondering about the context switch overhead if the processes aren't each running on a separate core.

Comment: @rcgldr It is really so kind of you. I have changed the work to be five million elements. The result is even crazy, more threads, lower run time... It drives me mad...

Comment: @rcgldr I really need your help. Actually, I am a new in multithread programming. Even, it can be said I am a fresher on programming. I am emergent with this task for teaching assistance duty. Could you please help me to go through this mess? I hope to contact you in person.

Comment: @MegaMM - what operating system are you running on? I only have Windows for the OS and Visual Studio to work with, which doesn't include pthreads. I can use std::thread, but I haven't done that before.

Comment: @rcgldr No matter how I tried, adding more threads increases the runing time... what wrong...

Comment: @rcgldr what is include <windows.h> ?

Comment: @MegaMM - windows.h is an include file that protypes the windows functions I used in my example, like CreateThread(), CreateSemaphore(), ...

Answer (score -1):

Don't understood why your question has been down voted. As I understood you have develop two programs with same operation. One you implemented with `multi process` and other one is with `multi thread`. First of all you need to know the difference between `multi process` and `multi thread`. I think you are using `fork()` in your `multi process` version. In `multi process` version, operating system create separate `data segment` for each process, hence while you are using `fork()` OS allocate a new memory space for the child process and copies all the memories from your parents process to newly created child process's memory location. But in the case of multi thread that never happens. So during memory access in multi threading environment, if you are using synchronize memory access the performance in `thread` version will be severely impacted but not in `multi process` version.

Comment: I think, -ve voter should explain why he voted -ve. That will improve our answer in future. I will delete if I get a proper explanation. Thanks

Comment: I didn't downvote (actually am here to perform research on downvoted answers), but the first 3 sentences seem to be a comment, not an answer to me. In addition, this answer is not that readable due to using `code` formatting for non-code, and not splitting into paragraphs. You're also missing the point of the question, which is not about process vs threads, but why the program gets slower with more threads.